# Menu items are not displayed in Bootstrap menu

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap menu and I face two issues. First one is that the menu items should be displayed on the right, but they don't show up.

The second is the mobile toggle button is displayed on the left side next to the logo all the time. it should only display when the screensize is smaller and it should be displayed on the right. I tried `navbar-toggler-right` but it didn't have any affect.

Here is my code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                <!-- <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>-->
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt=""></a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="resources.html">Resources</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

This is how it looks like now on desktop:

[image]

Comment: share your fiddle link or add your css

Answer (score 0):

By adding `navbar-expand-lg` to your nav class it will show.
Removing the container div and navbar-header div it will show the menu on the right.

Complete code:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt=""></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="resources.html">Resources</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```